# How to assign WRITE permission to IIS_IUSRS on a folder in a Docker container based on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, file-permissions, access-control

I am running a Docker container based on the following Windows Server 2019 core image:

`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`

This container is running an ASP.Net 4.8 application and writing to `logs` folder. Here is full path:

`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\logs`

My application is present on root of `wwwroot` folder. I am trying to give `Write` permission to user `IIS_IUSRS` on `logs` but keep getting following error:

> Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "This access
> control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be
> modified.

Here is my PowerShell code:

```
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("IIS_IUSRS", "Write", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl = Get-ACL "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Logs"
$acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
Set-ACL -Path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Logs" -ACLObject $acl
```

The error is coming on line 3 above where it calls `AddAccessRule`.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the error on the `AddAccessRule` command?

Comment: Error is given above. Anyway I fixed it by running this command `icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\logs /grant IIS_IUSRS:W /t /c` which will assign WRITE permission to `IIS_IUSRS`

Comment: Please put up an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

No need for PowerShell. Use the following command to set `WRITE` permission for `IIS_IUSRS`

`icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\logs /grant IIS_IUSRS:W /t /c`